# How to Configure "Tor Expert" to use http proxy on windows

Tags: proxy

How can i configure Tor Expert to connect through a http proxy? I had used Tor Browser bundle and there it is easy to configure a http/https proxy for tor but i wonder how i can redo it for tor expert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it's like this:

- Create a`torrc` file just where you have `tor.exe` file of the Tor Expert Bundle
- Open the `torrc` using a any text editor
- Add the following lines to it:

  ```
  HTTPSProxy YOUR_PROXY_IP_OR_ADDRESS
  HTTPSProxyAuthenticator YOUR_USERNAME:YOUR_PASSWORD
  ```
- open `tor.exe` using command line in the same folder with this command `tor.exe -f torcc`